# Car electronics

Tags: inverter, automatic-circuit-breaker

I have a vehicle with a 150 amp alternator and inverter 450w 12vdc input 115 back output
I want to run a tv for at least 4 hours TV is ac 110 60hz 48w typical power 28w I calculated my amps 0.4363636 ?
I have two batteries for separate power connected together and grounded to the van, batteries #1 say 40rpm vCard 60° 650 105rc 20ah rate db no.16  50 ? Batteries #2 says 495cca  55/56/62.   51255 ? My question is can I run a cable from the back batteries to my main battery do I need a relay or a fuze?[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a relay or fuze [sic].

However there is something you need to understand.

It's about the Cold Cranking Amp (CCA) rating.  When a battery has a CCA that means it is a starter battery.  It is not the type of battery you can discharge while watching TV than then recharge it like you do your mobile phone or laptop.

There are lead acid EV batteries used to power golf carts. These EV batteries do not have a CCA rating.  It is rated in Amp Hours.

Starter batteries are designed with low internal resistance by adding more thin plates for maximum surface area. It is designed to crank an engine for a second or two.

On the other hand the EV battery is Deep Cycle battery, not a starter battery.  Deep Cycle batteries have thick lead plates designed to provide continuous power.

Battery life is rated in cycle times with a depth of discharge percentage. This mean if you use your starter battery to watch TV, it will likely die after running the battery all the way down a dozen times.

The following image is from [Battery University, How does the Lead Acid Battery Work?](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/lead_based_batteries)   
This applies only to Lead Acid Batteries, and not Lithium (e.g. Li-ion) or Nickel (e.g. NiMH)

[image]